# Table not formatting properly

Tags: bug, formatting

I recently submitted an edit for the question [iMac Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017 won't boot after RAM upgrade to 64GB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450328/imac-retina-5k-27-inch-2017-wont-boot-after-ram-upgrade-to-64gb) which modified the information into a table. The edit was approved but when I went to look at it, the table didn't format properly:

[image: Screenshot of unformatted table]

If I go into edit the question, the preview for the question formats the table properly:

[image: Screenshot of edit with properly formatted table]

I viewed the posted question in the following browsers with the same results:

- Chrome v107.0.5304.110 (macOS)
- Safari v16.1 (macOS)
- Chrome v107.0.530 (iOS)
- Safari current version (iOS)
- Brave v1.45.123 (Win10)
- Chrome v107.0.5304.107 (Win10)
- Edge v107.0.1418.42 (Win10)

Is this a Stack issue or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding an empty line after the table, but it looks like a bug nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's formatting properly now. I will keep the "empty line" fix in mind if I need to make another table.